# How do I loop a MYSQL query multiple times and return the data from each looped query in node.js?

Tags: mysql, node.js, asynchronous, q

I have a database with a table called `Inventory` that has five columns: primary key, sku, item name, description, and price. I also have an array of SKUs called `skus`. My goal is to run a for-loop and query the `Inventory` table multiple times with each SKU to gather all of the information from each column about each SKU, and then output it.

I am fairly new to Node's asynchronous nature, and I'm having trouble with first obtaining all of the data from my table and THEN outputting it once it is all gathered and organized.

Here is my code:

```
var skus = [2, 1, 3, 4];

function inventoryLoop() {

    for(var i=0; i<skus.length; i++)
    {

        var deferred = Q.defer();

        connection.query("select * from Inventory where SKU = '"+skus[i]+"'", function(err, rows, fields) {

        deferred.resolve(rows);       

        }); //connection.query

    } //for-loop

    return deferred.promise;

} //inventoryLoop()


Q.all(inventoryLoop()).then(function(results) {

    console.log("results");        
    console.log(JSON.stringify(results));

}); //Q.all
```

This is my output:

```
[
    {"inventoryObjectID":2,"SKU":"2","itemName":"Lego 2","description":"Lego 2 Description","price":2}
]
```

This is the output I'm seeking:

```
Results
[
    {"inventoryObjectID":2,"SKU":"2","itemName":"Lego 2","description":"Lego 2 Description","price":2}
    {"inventoryObjectID":1,"SKU":"1","itemName":"Lego 1","description":"Lego 1 Description","price":1}
    {"inventoryObjectID":3,"SKU":"3","itemName":"Lego 3","description":"Lego 3 Description","price":3}
    {"inventoryObjectID":4,"SKU":"4","itemName":"Lego 4","description":"Lego 4 Description","price":4}
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you iterate over the list to fetch the information for each item individually you end up performing multiple queries to the database. Instead you can create a more complex query that will get you all the information you need and therefore reduce the number of queries you perform.

In your case, because you have a list of `sku` you can ran a query where it fetches all the rows that match that `sku`. You can do that with the following query:

`SELECT * FROM Inventory WHERE SKU='1' OR SKU='2' OR SKU='3' OR SKU='4'`

You can create yet a better query that results in the same output as follows:

`SELECT * FROM Inventory WHERE SKU IN ('1','2','3','4')`

You can therefore write your query as follows and avoid looping through the list:

`connection.query("SELECT * FROM Inventory WHERE SKU IN ("+skus+")",
   function(err, rows, fields) {...});`